# Executing kubectl on AWS CodeBuild connecting Amazon EKS Cluster does not work because of authentication problem

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-iam, kubectl, aws-codebuild, amazon-eks

`kubectl version` on CodeBuild prints error...

```
[Container] 2019/08/26 04:07:32 Running command kubectl version 
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15", GitVersion:"v1.15.0", GitCommit:"e8462b5b5dc2584fdcd18e6bcfe9f1e4d970a529", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-06-19T16:40:16Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"} 
error: You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials)
```

> error: You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials)

I'm using Amazon EKS Cluster.
It seems some authentication setup missing...?

What I did:

1. Setup codebuild project (a new service role `codebuild-hoge-service-role` is created).
2. Added `eks:DescribeCluster` Policy to the role as inline policy because `aws eks update-kubeconfig` requires it.
3. Edit `configmap/aws-auth` to bind the role and RBAC by `kubectl edit -n kube-system configmap/aws-auth` on my local device, adding new config to `mapRoles` like:

```
   mapRoles: |
     - rolearn: .....
     - rolearn: arn:aws:iam::999999999999:role/service-role/codebuild-hoge-service-role
     ¦ username: codebuild
     ¦ groups:
     ¦   - system:masters
```

That's all.
Not enough? Is there anything I missed?

Also I tried another approach to debug and it worked successfully..

1. Create a IAM User and IAM Role. He can switch to the role (assume role).
2. Edit `configmap/aws-auth` and Add config for the role. (same as failure process)
3. Switch role on local and execute `kubectl version`. It worked!!

buildspec.yml

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      docker: 18
    commands:
      - curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.15.0/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl
      - chmod +x ./kubectl
      - mv -f ./kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - aws eks update-kubeconfig --name mycluster
      - kubectl version
  build:
    commands:
      - kubectl get svc -A
```

Comment: getting the kubeconf using the role alone should work and do the trick for authentication.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue. I just had to create another role with same Trusted Relationship and policy as the original one. BUT it worked.

The only thing I did different was not add the path **/service-role/**, so the ARN looked like: `arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/another-codebuild-role`.

Comment: Can we mark this answer as good? This has been the solution after spending a good amount of hours researching why Codebuild could not interact with our kubernetes cluster

Comment: Definitely the correct answer. This is bl\*\*dy f\*\*king insane. Kudos to the dev team. How could anyone locate this error? This is some real genius and improvisation going on! Thanks a lot. It's been two long hours debugging this stupid s**t.

Comment: This is insane. I suspected the same and thankfully I came across this answer. Saved me a ton of time. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue today. The answers provided here do work, however in essence what you need to do is to remove the **/service-role** string from the role's ARN that you use in **aws-auth** config map. There is actually no need to create a separate role (in your IAM console you can keep the role with **/service-role** path in its ARN, remove it only in **aws-auth** config map).

Please see the following article for details: [AWS Knowledge Center Article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/codebuild-eks-unauthorized-errors/)